# How to retrieve messages from a Cursor

Tags: android

I have a query on Cursor.

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);
```

Above u can see that cursor has all the messages that inbox contain.
Now what i need is retriving all the messages from the inbox which has been received from a particular number.....

Thanks,

Pradeep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] smsNo=new String[]{"your_phone_number"};
Cursor cur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,"address=?", smsNo, null);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks XR....thanks a lot ... Its working ....can u explain me whats happening there..........